# Alert message when certain limit has been made

Tags: c#

I am creating a form for alerting the user that the stock for this item in the database is getting the limit or passed right through the limit.

this is my code for checking the quantity of a certain stock

```
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl_BloodChemistry where Glucose = "+123+" ";
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    count = count + 1;
}
if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Critical!");
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Aaaaaand what's your question?

Comment: Aaaaaand what's your used environment/technology?

Comment: Don't use a loop to get the count, use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` and `cmd.ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Aaaaaaaaand why don't you use `select count(*)...` instead?

Comment: Umpf — Is this health-related software that will run on some hardware, connected to actual persons?

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually the answer, but you have no reason to retrieve all data to collect count of rows. Use [SQL COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997(v=sql.120).aspx) and [ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

Also, it's important to use command [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to your query. Don't ever build a query in your way! The input variable, `Glucose`, is typically retrieved from a TextBox control on either a Windows form or a Web Page. Anything placed into that TextBox control will be put into inputCity and added to your SQL string. This situation invites a hacker to replace that string with something malicious. In the worst case, you could give full control of your computer away.

Instead of dynamically building a string, as shown in the bad example above, use parameters. Anything placed into a parameter will be treated as field data, not part of the SQL statement, which makes your application much more secure.

Using parameterized queries is a three step process:

1. Construct the `SqlCommand` command string with parameters.
2. Declare a `SqlParameter` object, assigning values as appropriate.
3. Assign the `SqlParameter` object to the `SqlCommand` object's Parameters property.

   ```
   var glucoseFilterValue = "123";
   conn.Open();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from tbl_BloodChemistry where Glucose = @Glucose";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Glucose", glucoseFilterValue);

   var count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   if (count == 1)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Critical!");
   }

   conn.Close();
   ```

Then you'll make your code more clean and prevent extra loading to your communication channel.

Comment: I won't upvote an answer which doesn't fix the missing parameter issue ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter He did change his code. Upvote now possible ;-)

Comment: Ok, +1 for following @TimSchmelter suggestion :)

Comment: I do think `var glucoseFilterValue = "+123+";` should read `var glucoseFilterValue = "123";`.